# Bootstrap 3 modal responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a modal but it's not resizing on smaller screens ( tablets, etc ). Is there a way to make it responsive ? Couldn't find any information on bootstrap docs. Thanks

I update my html code: ( its inside a django for loop )

```
    <div class="modal fade " id="{{ p.id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" >
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Producto</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <h5>Nombre : {{ p.name}}</h5>       
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I have these css settings:

```
.modal-lg {
  max-width: 900px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
   .modal-lg {
    width: 100%;
  } 
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .modal-lg {
    width: 900px;
  }
}
```

Comment: You could always resize it yourself using @media(max-width:500px) in your CSS

Comment: Your modal *should* resize as-is... post your code so we can see what's wrong.

Comment: I have my code updated, checked your suggestions but still isn't resizing .

Comment: [This](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-modals/) seems to be a good overview of bootstrap modals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue I have resolved by adding a media query for @screen-xs-min in less version under Modals.less

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs-min) {
  .modal-xs { width: @modal-sm; }
}
```

Answer (score 18):

From the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples):

Modals have two optional sizes, available via modifier classes to be placed on a `.modal-dialog`: `modal-lg` and `modal-sm` (as of 3.1).

Also the modal dialogue will [scale itself](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/12470) on small screens (as of 3.1.1).

Comment: This solved my issue, also found that I had some settings missing on my bootstrap.css file

Comment: That's working when I resize the screen, but modal isn't working on Android or any mobile devices. Not working inside buttons and not scrolling. Is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: Are you saying that something does not work in a browser installed on the phone? What exactly?

Comment: The modal buttons or modal scrolling for example. I manage to fix it following other post, but now I can't make the modal to pop up where I click, it opens the Modal on top of the page so I have to scroll all the way up to see it open.

Comment: Do you have `< meta name=”viewport” content=”width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0″ >` in your `<head>` section?

Answer (score 9):

You should be able to adjust the width using the `.modal-dialog` class selector (in conjunction with [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) or whatever strategy you're using for responsive design):

```
.modal-dialog {
    width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Old post. I ended up setting media queries and using `max-width: YYpx;` and `width:auto;` for each breakpoint. This will scale w/ images as well (per say you have an image that's 740px width on the `md` screen), the modal will scale down to 740px (excluding padding for the `.modal-body`, if applied)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="bs-button-info-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Button Information Modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that I'm using SCSS, bootstrap 3.3.7, and did not make any additional edits to the `_modals.scss` file that `_bootstrap.scss` imports. The CSS below is added to an additional SCSS file and imported AFTER `_bootstrap.scss`.

It is also important to note that the original bootstrap styles for `.modal-dialog` is not set for the default 992px breakpoint, only as high as the 768px breakpoint (which has a hard set width applied `width: 600px;`, hence why I overrode it w/ `width: auto;`.

```
@media (min-width: $screen-sm-min) { // this is the 768px breakpoint
    .modal-dialog {
        max-width: 600px;
        width: auto;
    }
}

@media (min-width: $screen-md-min) { // this is the 992px breakpoint
    .modal-dialog { 
        max-width: 800px;
    }
}
```

Example below of modal being responsive with an image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap modals are supposed to be responsive by default. Something to look out for is if you have a width set on your Modal. For example I had a form body container inside of my modal with a height of 40rem. If you change the width to 100% it will only take up as much space as it needs to and it will be responsive again. This example refers to inline styling.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and a easy way i found to solve that was to make everything in the modal's body responsive(using boostrap classes) and my problem were solved.