# Bootstrap modal too large

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

In my bootstrap modal, the content occupies a small part on the left side. However, the modal extends very much to the right.

[image]

The type of modal I am using:

```
<div id="newListModal" className="modal fade" role="dialog">
//some other code
</div>
```

How can I compress it such that it is only as large as the size of its content?

Comment: Do either of the [modal size options](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes) work for you?

Comment: What content will it contain? Normally, content stretches to fill or flow within the modal, not vice versa. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes

Comment: Small is almost ok, just a bit too small.

Comment: Here is a similar question with some good information, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974639/bootstrap-3-modal-responsive